# Possibility of extending Android phone call functionality

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-call

On a call android searches your contact list and shows the contact name if available, and if the number is an anonymous caller it just shows the number.

Now I want the call system to check a specific source (an XML file or a database file) after ending up searching in contact list and if the number is found in the source then show the name from the source.

Is it totally possible to add such thing to a built-in android function? If yes, could you please give me a clue to start from?

Answer (score 0):

If you make a custom dialer app, sure.  A special way to add it to any existing dialer app, not really.

Comment: The bad side of making a custom dialer is that I lose the real feel of the android dialer, and I doubt if a custom dialer can be as complete as the built-in one. And if it is impossible to extend the default dialer, can I write an app to check the result of default dialer contact check and if the number is anonymous then my app starts it search and tell the dialer to show this name?

Comment: The dialer is an app.  I can't even tell you what app it is, as different OEMs ship with different dialers (google provides a default one, but not everyone uses it).  But there is no generic way of providing data to any dialer app.  Specific dialers may have a way, but you can't depend on which one is installed.  The only way to do it is via custom dialer.  As for competing with the built in one-  depends on how much time you want to spend.  There's a lot of custom ones out there, at least some people must find them better.  But getting it to that level takes time.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I guess you could do similar like `2gis dialer` App. They just open custom dialog over the default dialer. [See left screen for example](http://www.droidnews.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/2gis_dialer_1.jpg)

Here another screens:
[First](http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3718/12055366796_706cfbb4f9_o.jpg), [Second](http://slon.ru/upload/iblock/4a1/2Gis_dialer_small.png), [Third](http://screens.dimonvideo.ru/android/navigaciya/big_383356_screenshot_2013-12-10-14-40-21.png)